# PS2 Keyboard interface runs smoothly in Active-HDL simulator, but not working on Nexys2 Board

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx-ise, active-hdl

I have to make a PS2 Keyboard Controller project at the university and i encountered a few problems when trying to test the system on the FPGA board.

It had worked perfectly in the simulator of Active-HDL, but i am not sure what it might be that stops it from working on the board, because when i try to program the board, the .bit file gets uploaded, but it does not react when i plug the PS/2 Keyboard in it and try to press a key.

I thought that probably a problem might be related to the PS/2 Keyboard protocol or the way it is synthesized for the board, but i really do not know.

The source code is here https://wetransfer.com/downloads/1d000a9feb241ff84693fca2084b0e9a20180513165005/8f7ca4 and the top level is called "ps2_top_src".
I am sorry for the way of uploading the code, but i couldn`t make it upload anywhere else.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please place the relevant code inside of your question, making a [mcve].

Comment: It is quite easy to have different simulation results then in-circuit results. That is because many constructs that are possible in VHDL are not properly synthesized. You need to follow the VHDL coding guidelines provided by you FPGA tool manufacturer.

Comment: For example this `process(clk, busyReceive_n) begin busyReceive <= busyReceive_n; end process;` (Core.vhd) simulates as a latch gated by clk but won't synthesize that way and won't show up in the latch log. The sensitivity list is ignored, it's an assignment statement, a different name for a wire. You'd think this should have been an edge sensitive sequential element (a register, for a single bit a flip flop). There are other suspicious constructs such as latches implied where perhaps they shouldn't. Design HW, not SW noting the parentheses around conditions. See xst.pdf for coding techniques.